# Only four out of seven ports working on an external USB hub

Tags: macos, usb, usb-hub

None of the previous questions answer mine:

I have a [XCD Super Speed USB Hub (with 7 Ports)](https://www.jbhifi.com.au/computers-tablets/accessories/xcd/xcd-7-port-usb-3-0-hub/560543/) which—to my knowledge—had 4-5 work ports—that I was using—until a few days ago. Now only ports 1 to 3 work and 4 to 7 do not work.

I have reset my MacBook Air several times, yet unaware how to reset the USB Hub itself as the reseting the Mac is not resetting the USB hub.

I have it also plugged into an adapter for power so that's not the issue.

Does anyone know how I can get the other ports working? I believe it would have happened when I pulled the device out without properly ejecting it (rather it fell out when I was moving my computer around).

I have attached some screensshots of the Apple system report showing USB details.

Thank you so much!

[image]

[image]

Comment: USB hubs are among the worst devices as far as their record of service life.  There is a very high percentage of crap being manufactured.  If you look at the reviews on the product link in your question, 6 of 7 reviewers gave it 1 star.  The 7th reviewer gave it 2 stars.  That's about the worst reviews I recall seeing for anything, and most reviewers cited the same problem you're having.  Don't waste time trying to fix it.  Just buy another hub (and don't set unrealistic expectations for that one either).

Comment: There really isn't fixing any modern electronics.  When individual components cost more than the entire devices (due to the lack of scale) it simply isn't worth repairing.